# Rewriting Relationships

Tags: functions

So I was looking at the function $y = \ln(x+\ln(x+\ln(x+\ln(x...$

I was thinking, how could someone possibly evaluate this??

Then, I noticed that if I removed a log, I would have $e^y = x+y$.

Boom, easy closed expression.

Now, I think, under what circumstances can I take a CLOSED FORM relationship and convert it to a format like above?

Like for example, I can write $y = \sqrt{2-x\sqrt{2-x\sqrt{2-x\dots}}} $ as $y^2=2-xy$, but what tells me that I can write the latter as the first??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What lets you do this is merely the fact that:

> If you take something from infinity ($\infty)$, then what you have left is *still
>   infinity*.

This is the main concept that is involved in this type of calculations.

As for this equation of yours,
$$y = \sqrt{2-x\sqrt{2-x\sqrt{2-x\dots}}} $$
$y$ is an infinite series of radicals.

First you square both sides, then you subtract $2$ from both sides and then you divide both sides by $-x$. Even after all these operations, what you've got is still an infinite series of radicals which as you have defined above is $y$.